# How to add delay before application loads in .net?

Tags: .net, delay

I am coding a program in vb.net but I am facing a trouble which I don't know how to fix.

I have 3 forms.

```
Form 1 = Loading   
Form 2 = Successfully loaded    
Form 3 = Main
```

So, when the program starts, it opens the loading form and it is waiting until the program is loaded. I want to add a delay of 10 seconds after the load before the success page shows.

So, I tried these methods:

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000)
```

But it freezes the application and it doesn't work as intended, it shows the application before 10 seconds.

And I also tried with Timer, setting the interval to 10,000 but it doesn't seem to work, it displays the form instantly.

Any alternative solutions???

My code:

```
Public Class Loading

    Private Sub Loading_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Timer1.Start()
        Me.Hide()
        Success.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Timer1.Interval = 10000
        Timer1.Stop()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: `it opens the loading form and it is waiting until the program is loaded` => Do you mean your form instead of program? Why don't you raise an event when the form is loaded and catch it in the main form? 10 seconds may be huge on some machines but perhaps not enough on others. You shouldn't stop the user for 10 seconds (a long time) if not needed, or you may also want to reconsider the way your application load forms.

Comment: Yes I mean form. I updated my code in the first post, check it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the best way is to use a [timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx).

1. Create a timer with an interval of 10000ms
2. Show the message in the elapsed event
3. Dispose the timer

Comment: I already tried, check my code in first post, when I Run the application, both the loading and success forms show for some reason...

Comment: You should call Success.Show() in the timer elapsed event. Right now you are calling it immediately after the timer start.

Comment: You're correct. All I had to do was move the code to the Timer and it works perfectly now. Thank you!

Comment: @user2699298: Your problem may be fixed but I think there is a better way to implement this.